# How do I get Ubuntu Update Manager to nag me only about my current version?

Tags: upgrade

I have Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS installed. At some point, I accidentally asked to upgrade to 16.04 LTS, but noticed it was a new number version and canceled the upgrade, as I'm trying to keep my Ubuntu version in sync with another computer that's not under my control.

However, Ubuntu's Update Manager keeps nagging me to upgrade to 16.04 LTS.

I have the Software & Updates control panel set to Notify me of a new Ubuntu version for LTS support version.

I **do** want the manager to notify me for, say, the availability of 14.04.6, just not for some other whole-number version. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Won't setting it to never check for a new release work? It'll still update if a new point release of 14.04 comes out, since that happens in normal `apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the updates for your current release and prevent notifications for future Ubuntu version you should set the *Notify me of a new Ubuntu version* to `Never` as shown below.

[image: Software & Updates | Updates]